# Create a backup RedHat DVD

Tags: backup, redhat, installation, optical-media

Okay I am kind of desperate here. I took a simple backup of my RedHat EL 5 install DVD and now  that backup DVD refuses to boot .. 
Some googling told me that my backup DVD is probably not bootable .
I don't have the original DVD now. Is there a way to make my backup DVD bootable ? 
I am on win XP now and have no access to Linux tools :(

TIA,
Akeshi

Answer (score 1):

If you know your Red Hat Network support account and password, you can get the media from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the exact RedHat install, you can use CentOS instead, and replace the contents of /etc/redhat-release file with the official redhat string.

If not, contact RH support and get a new download from them.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possibilities here, either:

1) You are a paying Redhat customer in which case you can login to the Redhat website and just download the ISO image(s) again

2) You're not a paying Redhat customer in which case you should head over to centos.org and download the Centos ISO images (Centos is a free, as-close-as-possible, clone of Redhat Enterprise Linux built from the same source packages)

Answer (score 0):

This is a [***best dvd backup software***](http://www.aimersoft-mac.com/dvd-backup-mac.html#131) for you to backup dvd movies whenever and whatever you want.